# Building a zip compressor/decompressor to refine C skills

Tags: c, compression, zip

I want to refine my C skills and have been thinking of trying to write my own zip and unzip program. This seems hit on a lot of areas, CPU/HDD/Memory.

Where do I start? Is there a flow chart of what to do to compress and uncompress? Is it too complicated for this type of project?

A good book that steps through all the steps to take or a site?

I wonder if anyone has any good resources for this or maybe any additional suggestions.

Comment: Having only the answer to one question, I'm posting this as a comment, but I think this is a great idea for a learning project. It may be too ambitious depending on your previous C experience, but it's a fairly clearly defined problem with programs that solve it that you can look at if you get stuck. Plus, you have an easy way to verify if it works.

Comment: Note: Once you get to the point where you can get your own program to work to decompress and compress its own files, the next step is to make it compatible with other programs (i.e. decompress zip files it did not create, have other programs compress files it did create).  That is worthwhile in terms of real-world programming with interoperability concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read up on [Huffman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) on wikipedia. The encoding is pretty simple, and you can achieve some level of compression with this. This compression algorithm will help you with linked lists, memory allocation-deallocation, and correct choice of data structures.

If you want to implement something extremely simple, just implement [Run Length Encoding.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Comment: +1 For suggesting both Huffman encoding and Run Length Encoding, as they're both nice choices for learning.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by having a good look at the external links at the following wikipedia pages (they link to full specifications of the format):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE

Answer (score 1):

Additional suggestion, just in case you are looking for something more difficult.

The program [Crinkler](http://www.pouet.net/nfo.php?which=18158&f=none) specializes in compressing small executables. Here is [info](http://in4k.untergrund.net/index.php?title=Crinkler) about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

ZIP is a combination of 2 things, a file packaging format and a (set of) compression algorithms. The first is a bit prosaic but would hone your bit-didling skills, the second more interesting and advanced.

I remember having to implement LZW encoding and decoding in C in order to read and write GIF files. This would be a fine project, as LZW compression is very very clever - one of the only algorithms I've seen that I think deserves a patent, and a much more achievable aim than ZIP

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at open source applications like Zip, Gzip, Bzip, and 7-Zip, which implement their own variations on the whole compress files thing.  7-Zip specifically has their own compression format (7z) that actually gets files smaller than if you were to use straight zip, so there's something to be learned there.

I'm not saying copy their code or anything but looking at something someone has done before can usually get the wheels turning and get you to think about the problem in a different way that will help you get some forward momentum.